# Conditional that looks at URL

Tags: routes

Im attempting to wrap my secondary links in an if statment that looks at the URL and only displayes them if URL is work/*.

The secondary links are only related to work but show on every page so i am trying to emove on any path that is not work/*. The secondary links are within my page.tpl

Ive been tryin with this but no joy.

```
 <?php  if ($the_url = explode('/', urldecode(request_url('work')))):?>
         <div id="secondary-links-wrap"><?php if (!empty($secondary_links)){ print theme('links', $secondary_links, array('id' => 'secondary', 'class' => 'links sub-menu')); } ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be much appretiated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$request_array = explode('/', request_uri());
if (in_array('work', array_values($request_array))) {
  //execute your custom code
}
```

Comment: Can you please flag it as the answer?  Thanks! :)